# How can you unshift each element of the list with immutable js?

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, redux, immutability

I want to unshift each element of an array in immutable list

My execution resulted in the following.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nprD4.png)

-> List[List[new_element], element, element, element]

I want this result.

-> List[new_element, element, element, element]

How can i fix it?

---

```
case types.MEMO_LIST_SUCCESS:

    if (action.listType === 'new') {        
        if(action.data.length !== 0) {
            return state.setIn(['memoList', 'status'], 'SUCCESS')
                                .setIn(['memoList', 'data'], data.unshift(fromJS(action.data)));
        } else {
            return state.setIn(['memoList', 'status'], 'SUCCESS')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the expression `action.data.length` in your code example it looks like you should iterate `action.data` and add each item to `data`.

> If `action.data` is an array or other iterable, `fromJS(action.data)` will return you a new `List`.

---

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` and pass `data` as initial value for the accumulation, adding to it by iterating `action.data`:

```
if (action.listType === 'new') {
    const newData = action.data.reduce((acc, item) => acc.unshift(fromJs(item)), data);
    return state
        .setIn(['memoList', 'status'], 'SUCCESS')
        .setIn(['memoList', 'data'], newData);
}
```

Or even easier, use the [`List::concat`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/concat) method.

Note that the above example reverses the order of items in of `action.data`, whereas the following example does not.

Also the example above does convert each `item` to immutable `List` or `Map` if it is an array resp. object, whereas the following example does not.

```
if (action.listType === 'new') {
    return state
        .setIn(['memoList', 'status'], 'SUCCESS')
        .setIn(['memoList', 'data'], fromJS(action.data).concat(data));
}
```

Comment: It was very helpful.